# Absolute and uniform convergence of the series $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\varphi(x+k)$ on $[-1,1]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ a function such that $|\varphi(x)|=O\left(\frac{1}{|x|^{m}}\right)$ as $|x|\to\infty$ where $m>1$. Then, I want to show that the sum $\sum_{k\in\mathbb{Z}}\varphi(x+k)$ exists for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ and converges absolutely and uniformly in $[-1,1]$ using Weierstrass M-test but I got stuck on it even if it is not using Weierstrass M-test.

What I used is that $|\phi(x+k)|\le \frac{A}{|x+k|^m}$ for some $A>0$ and for $|x+k|>M$ but I cannot find a bound for $\frac{A}{|x+k|^m}$ that doesn't depends on $x$.

Any hint will be appreciate it.

Comment: What difficulties did you encounter?

Comment: Finding the constanst $M_{k}$ such that $|\varphi(x+k)|\leq M_{k},\qquad\forall x\in [-1,1]$ and for all $x\in [-1,1]$.
Even I don't know how to show that the sum exists for $x\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But you haven't used the bound $O(1/|x|^m)$ yet....

Comment: What I used is that $|\varphi(x+k)|\leq\frac{A}{|x+k|^{m}}$ for some $A>0$ and for $|x+k|>M$ but I cannot find a bound for $\frac{A}{|x+k|^{m}}$ that doesn't depends on $x$